# crazy jquery problem working with mozilla and not in others

Tags: jquery

i have this code

```
$(function() { $('#ans_vote a span').click(function(){alert('working');return false;});});
```

and this html

```
<div id="ans_vote">
<a href='#'><span>one</span></a>
</div>   

<div id="ans_vote">
<a href='#'><span>two</span></a>
</div>
```

when click one and two in mozilla its working
but when click one in ie its working but when click two its not working

Comment: @moustafa sorry m8 we're not in your head the `when click one and two in mozilla its working but when click one in ie its working but when click two its not working` its absolutely impossible to figure out, why don't you break it down.. what is working and what is not .. for now

Comment: when i change it $('.ans_vote a span') and change the containar to class it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`id` should be unique. Use classes instead!

```
<script>
$(function(){ 
    $('.ans_vote a span').click(function(){
        alert('working');return false;
    });
});
</script>

<div class="ans_vote">
<a href='#'><span>one</span></a>
</div>   

<div class="ans_vote">
<a href='#'><span>two</span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

This should be on the front page of SO all the time: your "id" values **must be unique within a page.**

Comment: That is why it is called **ID** : Identifier which uniquely identifies an element. +1

Answer (score 1):

i placed your jQuery function into `$(document).ready(function() {....}` and it's works in IE(version 8) too. but i recommend to you use unique id's for divs.